# problem about heat in thermodynamics

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium

$$\nabla G=-T\nabla S-T\nabla S_{sur}=-Q+q
  $$

$$\nabla G=-T\nabla S-T\nabla S_{sur}=-(U-W_{rew})+q
  $$

$$\nabla G=-T\nabla S-T\nabla S_{sur}=-(q+W-W_{rew})+q
  $$

$$\nabla G=-T\nabla S-T\nabla S_{sur}=-W+W_{rew}=-p_{ext}dV+pdV     
  $$

By defintion we have that $$\nabla G$$

in the end will determine equilibrium concentrations. This means that if $$p_{ext}>p$$

energy will be accelerated into the system from the surroundings. My problem is that I wanted to prove mathematically that this Acceleration would make a reaction happen no matter what if we let time go to infinity as gibbs theorem says. So from what I would believe I would need proof that says that Acceleration increases over the long run until the reaction moves to a direction and $$\nabla G=0$$

This makes sense to me for ideal gases bot I wondered if one could show that this mathematically makes sense for non ideal equilibriums where there is an activation energy from electric forces that needs to be overcome for the reaction to occour. I believe there would be 3 scenarios: gas phase, Liquid phase and solid phase.